# 2 monitors, 2 computers and a docking station for one

Tags: windows-8, kvm-switch

I have a desktop computer and a work computer (IBM thinkpad) which is connected to a docking station.  Attached to the work laptop (docking station) are two monitors.  What I want to do is have access to both monitors from both my desktop and laptop through the use of a KVM switch.  Does anyone know if a kvm will work with a docking station?

Comment: A KVM just passes input one way and output the other way. If all the right ports are there, it could care less what is on either end of the cables.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar setup and use [InputDirector](http://www.inputdirector.com/). It's basically a virtual KVM. You install it on both machines. Configure one to be the master and another the slave. Configure where the various monitors are and whether you want the mouse to wrap or not. It also has a "shared" clipboard so you can copy/paste text between the two machines. It's free for personal use.

Highly recommended.

[image: http://www.inputdirector.com/images/features_cursortransition.jpg]

Comment: A KVM switches keyboard, mouse and video.  Does this switch video?

Comment: It doesn't switch but allows you to work on multiple computers with one keyboard and one mouse much like a KVM would. I realize the OP was about a KVM but I've switched to using these 'virtual' kvms and haven't looked back.

Comment: But because the video doesn't switch, you need twice as many monitors (and desk space).

Comment: If you read the question the OP already has multiple monitors. I have the same setup at work I have a desktop hooked up to a monitor and a laptop with a docking station (also hooked up to a monitor for a total of three screens). I use ID to have one keyboard and mouse control both machines. I felt my experience with this setup would help the OP.

Comment: Yes I read the question.  The OP wants to use display each computer across his multiple monitors.  Note that I didn't say "you need two monitors", I said "you need *twice as many*" and meant it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am not sure what your point is. Neither this answer nor the one about Synergy claim they are real KVM switches but that they solve similar problems. Just maybe the OP hasn't heard of them before and they might solve his problem (in an XY sort of way).

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org). It works for Windows, Linux and Mac Os X.

It's a virtual KVM just like InputDirector.

It works great. I've a similar setup with one mac and a thinkpad. Used it for years.

Comment: I like Synergy, but I'm not sure it addresses the OP's issue.  He wants to use both monitors on one machine.  Synergy just lets you move between the two machines seamlessly using a single keyboard and mouse.

Comment: I use input director with two monitors on the laptop and one on the desktop. These programs handle multi-monitor set-ups.

Comment: Synergy certainly does not qualify as a KVM, as it switches keyboard and mouse only, not video.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know if a kvm will work with a docking station?

Yes.  You'll obviously need a KVM switch that supports two monitors (Startech makes one), but you should have no problems using a KVM switch with a docking station.

The bigger question is whether your work laptop has a way of connecting two monitors.  A KVM switch won't help if your work laptop doesn't have anyplace to connect the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Docking stations and KVMs don't mix very well. It depends on the brands, I guess.

I have the HP docking station and the IOGEAR KVM, and they are not working very well together. I have to plug the USB cable from the KVM directly into the laptop instead of the docking station. If I don't do it this way, the laptop won't boot.